# Powershell Script step in a Deployment Group Job generates this error: The type initializer for System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Initializ

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a `Deployment Group Job` in a `Release Pipeline` where I have a step to execute an Inline powershell script. 3 out of 10 times, the step generates the following error

> Windows Powershell terminated with the following error The type
> initializer for
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState threw an
> exception

Not only that, the error message appears to be in some weird codepage where each character is 2 bytes and the console prints a `?` for the unknown byte in between each two letters.

What could be happening? These are my on-premise agent registered with Azure DevOPS.